# Write to a reg's bitfields via alias names in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have a register:

```
reg [7:0] dout; //output of memory bus
```

Groups of bits in dout represent something meaningful like:

- dout[2:0] is a state
- dout[3] is a flag
- dout[7:4] is some data

I want to read and write to this register dout from inside an always statement. I want to address it using these labels.
This example conveys my attempt:

```
reg [7:0] dout; //output of memory bus

wire [2:0] dout_state;
wire dout_flag;
wire [3:0] dout_data;

//alias labels
assign dout_state[2:0] = dout[2:0];
assign dout_flag = dout[3];
assign dout_data = dout[7:4];

always(@posedge clk) begin
    dout_state <= 3'b1;
    dout_flag <= 1'b1;
end
```

The procedural assignments fail because dout_state and dout_flag are wires.

I want these labels to work as aliases that represent portions of the dout bus.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The always block already drives `dout_state` and `dout_flag` signals, so the other assignments should be reversed. Your current code never drives `dout`.

```
//alias labels
assign dout[2:0] = dout_state;
assign dout[3] = dout_flag;
assign dout[7:4] = dout_data;
```

Now the signal definitions also should be updated. If `dout` is a port, the `reg` definition should be removed. If not, it should be a `wire`.

```
wire [7:0] dout; //output of memory bus
```

Because of the always block, `dout_state` and `dout_flag` signals should be `reg`.

```
reg [2:0] dout_state;
reg dout_flag;
```